# How can I handle an error on installing SELinux policy

Tags: installation, cil, selinux

Now I'm trying to install SELinux policy that I made.
But I met error like follow:

Failed to resolve filecon statement at /var/lib/selinux/targeted/tmp/modules/400/mypolicy/cil:303
semodule:  Failed!
install failed :

I hope to know how can I handle this error. How can I find the error point in the .te or .fc file?
What does the number '303' mean? Is it a line number? But cil file is binary.
Could you please let me know a way to handle this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reason.
In RH8, umask is added to /etc/pam.d/postlogin. So, for sFtp, the UMASK value in /etc/login.defs is pulled and it is applied to umask value for sFtp. It was 077.

[Redhat link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1777718)

Answer (score 0):

The transformation of your `.te` `.if` and `.fc` files into the actual policy is a multi-step process.

When the system builds a policy module, first, checkmodule is used to construct a .mod intermediate file. Next, semodule_package is called, transforming this intermediate file and the corresponding file-context file into a .pp file.

In your error, `semodule` now complains about some problem in the policy package and gives the corresponding Common Intermediate Language line number as a reference. If you want to know more about CIL, see here: https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux/blob/master/secilc/docs/README.md

To get the failing line within the CIL file, locate your pp file and call the pp compiler to get the CIL code. The pp compiler is in the High-Level Language Infrastructure folder called hll (see https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux/wiki/High-Level-Language-Infrastructure).

```
/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/libexec/selinux/hll/pp ./refpolicy/mypolicy.pp > mypolicy.txt
```

Now you can check the given line number in the mypolicy.txt.